# TypeError: Cannot read property 'hello' of undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to run below program. I have one function `hello` and I am calling it inside `b`. It gives me an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'hello' of undefined

```
class ChildClass {
  // constructor
  constructor(param, ...args) {

    this.hello = function (a) {
      console.log(a);
    }

    this.obj = {
      a: {
        b() {
          this.hello(2)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: `this` inside the `b()` function will point to the `this.a` object

Comment: `this` in the `b` method refers not to the object of the `ChildClass`

Comment: @AndreiCACIO Yup. How I can make such that `hello` is available inside b()

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work.

Comment: Related: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Technically we have to see how you are calling the function to what `this` will refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this` isn't pointing to the `ChildClass` instance but to the inner `a` object. One solution might be:

```
class ChildClass {
  // constructor
  constructor(param, ...args) {

    const hello = this.hello = function (a) {
      console.log(a);
    }

    this.obj = {
      a: {
        b() {
         hello(2)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However if you don't intend to use `hello()` as an instance method, you can simply declare it in a private `const` and don't put it on `this`:

```
class ChildClass {
  // constructor
  constructor(param, ...args) {

    const hello = function (a) {
      console.log(a);
    }

    this.obj = {
      a: {
        b() {
         hello(2)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Depends on what you want to do.

Or, you can save the "real" `this` in a `const`:

```
class ChildClass {
  // constructor
  constructor(param, ...args) {
    const instance = this;

    this.hello = function (a) {
      console.log(a);
    }

    this.obj = {
      a: {
        b() {
         instance.hello(2)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```